# Cannot link SDL2 statically

Tags: c++, g++, ld, sdl-2

I'm trying to link to SDL2 statically on Arch Linux in order to produce single, cross-platform executable for a game. SDL2 headers are installed in /usr/include/SDL2, and libraries in /usr/lib. Compiling dynamically with `g++ -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2 hello.cpp` works, as ./a.out produces a blank window, but I am unable to link SDL2 to the executable statically.

Contents of hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

int main() {
    bool quit{false};
    SDL_Event inputEvent;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 1280, 0);

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&inputEvent);

        switch (inputEvent.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    std::cout << "Bye!";
    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -I/usr/include/SDL2 -static -lSDL2 hello.cpp` returns `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2`, while `g++ -I/usr/include/SDL2 -l:libSDL2 hello.cpp` returns `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libSDL2`.

Comment: Beware that once you link statically rather than dynamically, things change (legally) regarding licences - LGPL and GPL specifically.

Comment: SDL2, unlike SDL 1.x, is zlib licensed, so static linking should be permitted, right?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV. I'm just saying that how you link *may* change legal things. Nothing else.

Comment: You never mentioned where is your `libSDL2.a` placed. (a bit of general information just in case - `.so` libraries are intended for dynamic linking, `.a` are static archives; ld says it can't find requested library, what's the reason to think it should?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that PKGBUILD of sdl2-hg in the AUR was renaming `libSDL2.a` to `libSDL2main.a`, hence the `libSDL2.a not found` error. Removing the problematic line from the PKGBUILD and recompiling SDL2 alleviated the issue.